# Is my CA doing anything?

Tags: certificate-authority

One of our DC's is running the CA role. It was installed a long time ago, and I don't think it serves a purpose anymore. I would like to remove the role, but is there a way to determine if in fact Certificate Authority is actually doing anything.

Thank you.

Comment: One way to get an insite would be to check if the CA cert is still valid. Also, no one outside your workplace can answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to load the Certificate Authority's management console and check if it's issuing any certificates. Using the CA console you can also check if the root certificate is still valid (they're usually good for 10+ years from first installation).

If it hasn't issued any certificates in a long time, and all the existing certificates it has issued have expired, then it's *probably* safe to decommission (check with someone else in your company if you can).

It's not just as simple as uninstalling the role - [see this Microsoft doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/889250/how-to-decommission-a-windows-enterprise-certification-authority-and-r).